# A property of an Archimedean cyclically ordered group

Tags: group-theory, order-theory

I am trying to prove the following property:

**Lemma** (?). For any non-negative element $x$ of an Archimedean cyclically ordered group there is a non-negative element $y$ such that $x + y$ is non-positive.

Proof (?):

For a non-negative element $x$ of an Archimedean cyclically ordered group:

1. Case $x = -x$:

   - $-x$ is not negative;
   - $x + (-x) = 0$ is not positive;
2. Case $[0, x, -x]$:

   - Applying Archimedean property: not $[0, nx, -x]$ for some $n \in \mathbb N; n \gt 1$;

     - Case $nx = 0$: $nx$ is not positive;
     - Case $nx = -x$: $nx$ is negative;
     - Case $[0, -x, nx]$:

       - Applying formula $[0, a, b] \iff [0, -b, -a]$: $[0, -x, nx] \iff [0, -nx, x]$;
       - Applying transitivity to $[0, -nx, x]$, $[0, x, -x]$, and $[0, -x, nx]$: $[0, -nx, nx]$;
       - $nx$ is negative.
   - For all the cases from 2: $x$ is positive, but $nx$ is not positive for some $n \in \mathbb N, n > 1$. Therefore, there is $k \in \mathbb N; k \lt n$: $kx$ is positive, but $(1 + k)x = x + kx$ is not positive.

Could somebody verify if it is correct, please?

An element $x$ of a cyclically ordered group is positive (negative) iff $[0, x, -x]$ ($[0, -x, x]$).

Comment: What does $[0,x,-x] ([0,-x,x])$ mean? That $x$ is between $0$ and $-x$ cyclically or something? I have not seen that notation...

Comment: @coffeemath: It is the ternary relation of a cyclic order (from Wikipedia Cyclic order).