# The rule of three steps for a cyclically ordered group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory

Is this rule correct?
If yes, is there a better way to prove it?
If not, what would be an example that does not satisfy the rule?

**Theorem**. For any element $a$ of a group with a non-linear cyclic order there is a combination of not more than three non-negative elements $b$, $c$, $d$ such that $a + b + c + d = 0$.
If the cyclic order is Archimedean or it has an apex, then there is a combination of not more than two non-negative elements $b$, $c$ such that $a + b + c = 0$.

**Corollary**. For any positive element $a$ of a group with a non-linear cyclic order there is a combination of not more than three positive elements $b$, $c$, $d$ such that $a + b + c + d = 0$.

([Positive and negative elements of a cyclically ordered group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2213048/427611))

Proof:

**Lemma 1**. For any non-negative element $x$ of an Archimedean cyclically ordered group there is a non-negative element $y$ such that $x + y$ is non-positive ([A property of an Archimedean cyclically ordered group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205470/a-property-of-an-archimedean-cyclically-ordered-group)).

**Lemma 2**. If $z$ is an apex, then $x + z$ is negative (positive) for any positive (negative) $x$ ([Apex of a cyclically ordered group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2204247/an-apex-of-a-cyclically-ordered-group)).

- Any cyclically ordered group $G$ has a representation $K \times L$ where $K$ is an Archimedean cyclically ordered group, and $L$ is a linearly ordered group (*Swierczkowski*, *Jakubik*, *Pringerova*);
- The cyclic order on $G$ is not linear $\iff$ $K$ is not trivial;
- Checking all possible cases for an element $g = (k, x), k \in K, x \in L$:

  1. Case $L$ is trivial: $G = K$, $G$ is Archimedean;

     - Case $g$ is negative:

       - $g' = –g$ is positive,
       - $g + g' = 0$;
     - Case $g$ is not negative:

       - Applying Lemma 1 to $G$: there is a non-negative $g'$: $g + g'$ is not positive;
       - $g'' = -(g + g')$ is not negative;
       - $g + g' + g'' = 0$;
  2. Case $L$ is not trivial: $G$ is not Archimedean since $[(0, 0), n(0, x), (0, -x)]$ for any $x > 0, n \in \mathbb N$;

     - Case $g = 0$;
     - Case $g$ is negative or an apex:

       - $g' = –g$ is not negative;
       - $g + g' = 0$;
     - Case $g$ is positive:

       - Case $k$ is an apex in $K$ $(x < 0)$:

         - An element $g' = (k, 0)$ is an apex in $G$;
         - Applying Lemma 2: $g + g’$ is negative;
         - $g'' = -(g + g')$ is positive;
         - $g + g' + g'' = 0$;
       - Case $k$ is positive in $K$ $(\forall x \in L)$. Applying Lemma 1 to $K$:
         there is a non-negative $k'$ such that $k + k'$ is not positive.

         - Case $k’ = 0$ is not applicable: $k + 0$ is positive;
         - Case $k’$ is an apex in $K$: $g' = (k', 0)$ is an apex in $G$, reviewed;
         - Case $k'$ is positive in $K$:

           - Case $k + k' = 0$ is not applicable: $k' = -k$ is negative;
           - Case $k + k'$ is an apex in $K$: reviewed;
           - Case $k + k'$ is negative in $K$:

             - $g' = (k', 0)$ is positive;
             - $g + g' = (k + k', x)$ is negative;
             - $g'' = -(g + g')$ is positive;
             - $g + g' + g'' = 0$;
       - Case $k = 0$ $(x > 0)$. $K$ is non-trivial; therefore, there is an element $k' ≠ 0$;

         - Case $k'$ is an apex in $K$: reviewed;
         - Case $k'$ is positive in $K$:

           - An element $g' = (k', 0)$ is positive;
           - $g + g' = (k', x)$ is positive;
           - Applying the case for a positive element $(k', x)$ with a positive $k'$:
              there is a combination of not more than two non-negative elements $g'', g'''$ such that
             $g + g' + g'' + g''' = 0$;
         - Case $k'$ is negative in $K$: applying the previous case with $k'' = -k'$.

Comment: What is a cyclic order?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order

Comment: Sorry to waste your time - I should have googled that myself!

Comment: @JasonDeVito: I think that was the right question since the notation in Wikipedia differ from other works (“First order theory of cyclically ordered groups” https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0499.pdf).

Comment: Having perused the wikipedia article, what does non-negative mean in this context?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: a non-negative element is an element that is not negative. An element $x$ is negative iff $[0, -x, x]$. $0$ and $apex$ are not negative and not positive.