# A property of a cyclic order on a ring

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, order-theory

Is this property correct?
If yes, is there a better way to prove it?
If not, what would be an example of a ring that does not satisfy the condition?

**Theorem**. In a ring with non-linearly cyclically ordered additive group there is no such element $x$ that $[0, ax, a]$ for any *positive* element $a$.

Proof:

From the properties of [Positive and negative elements of a cyclically ordered group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213048/positive-and-negative-elements-of-a-cyclically-ordered-group):

**Lemma 1.11**. If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are *positive* elements of a cyclically ordered group such that $a + b + c = 0$, and $[0, a', a]$, $[0, b', b]$, $[0, c', c]$ for some elements $a'$, $b'$, $c'$, then $a' + b' + c' \ne 0$.

**Lemma 1.12**. If $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are *positive* elements of a cyclically ordered group such that $a + b + c + d = 0$, and $[0, a', a]$, $[0, b', b]$, $[0, c', c]$, $[0, d', d]$ for some elements $a'$, $b'$, $c'$, $d'$, then $a' + b' + c' + d' \ne 0$.

- Applying [The rule of three steps for a cyclically ordered group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208205/the-rule-of-three-steps-for-a-cyclically-ordered-group) to the additive group of a ring: for a *positive* element $a$ there is a combination of not more than three *positive* elements $b$, $c$, $d$: $a + b + c + d = 0$;
- Case $a + b = 0$ is not applicable since $b = -a$ is *negative*;
- Case $a + b + c = 0$:

  - Assuming there is an element $x$: $[0, ax, a]$, $[0, bx, b]$, $[0, cx, c]$;
  - Applying lemma 1.11: $a + b + c = 0 \implies ax + bx + cx \ne 0$;
  - Applying distributivity: $ax + bx + cx = (a + b + c)x = 0$; contradiction;
- Case $a + b + c + d = 0$:

  - Assuming there is an element $x$: $[0, ax, a]$, $[0, bx, b]$, $[0, cx, c]$, $[0, dx, d]$;
  - Applying lemma 1.12: $a + b + c + d = 0 \implies ax + bx + cx + dx \ne 0$;
  - Applying distributivity: $ax + bx + cx + dx = (a + b + c + d)x = 0$; contradiction.

Comment: Conerning Lemma 1: what about $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} = \{0,1,2\}$ ? Am I mistaken or, does this proof it wrong: $2 + 1 = 0$

Comment: @hillbilly: in the ring with cyclically ordered additive group one of {1, 2} is negative.

Comment: I moved all lemmas related to positive elements of a cyclically ordered group into a separate question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213048/positive-and-negative-elements-of-a-cyclically-ordered-group